# How to use KivyMD Bottom Navigation to Switch between multiple screens

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to put KivyMD BottomNavigation on 4 of the screens in the `.kv` file below, I tried it before, but I had issues with kivymd toolbar (as I need different toolbar for different screens), and I couldn't come back to the screens which had the BottomNavigation (though I think am at fault, am using `app.change_screen()` = `'bottomnavigationitem name'` which is what I do for normal screens)

I currently have Kivymd BottomAppbar on the 4 screens, but cause of the bottomappbar transparency issues I want to change the BottomAppbar to BottonNavigation.

questions; (1) how do I place the toolbar in the MDBottomNavigation, since I want different toolbar for different screens (2) How do I switch back to the screens with the MDBottomNavigation, (cause I tried doing this before, it just returns a blank white screen)
Thank you..

here's my .py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, NoTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (300, 530)


class IntroScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WaysScreen(Screen):
    pass


class To_DoScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SuccessScreen(Screen):
    pass


class GoalsScreen(Screen):
    pass


class BellaBaron(Screen):
    pass


class SearchScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CalendarScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ExtraScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ArchiveScreen(Screen):
    pass


class Contact_InfoScreen(Screen):
    pass


class TenThousandApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Green'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = '200'
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.sm.add_widget(IntroScreen(name="intro_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(WaysScreen(name="ways_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(To_DoScreen(name="to_do_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(SuccessScreen(name="success_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(GoalsScreen(name="goals_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(BellaBaron(name="bella_baron"))
        self.sm.add_widget(SearchScreen(name="search_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name="menu_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(CalendarScreen(name="calendar_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(ExtraScreen(name="extra_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(ArchiveScreen(name="archive_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(Contact_InfoScreen(name="contact_info_screen"))

        return self.sm

    def change_screen(self, screen):
        self.sm.current = screen


TenThousandApp().run()
```

and here's my .kv

```
# The BottomAppBar in the Intro, Success, Search and Menu Screens..
# is what I want to change to BottomNavigation
<IntroScreen>
    name: "intro_screen"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: intro_screen_toolbar
            title: '[font=Gabriola][size=40][color=#FD0101]First[/color][/size][size=28]project[/size][/font]'
            right_action_items: [["calendar-month", lambda x: app.change_screen('to_do_screen')]] #links to to-do listss screen

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "280dp", "360dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - intro_screen_toolbar.height - dp(90)
            y: root.height - intro_screen_toolbar.height - dp(50)
            elevation: "8dp"
            orientation: 'vertical'
            radius: 15

            ScrollView:
                MDLabel:
                    markup: True
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text:
                        """[b][i]“Your time is limited, so don’t waste it living someone else’s life. Don’t be trapped by dogma – which is living with the results of other people’s thinking. Don’t let the noise of other’s opinions drown out your own inner voice. And most important, have the courage to follow your heart and intuition. They somehow already know what you truly want to become. Everything else is secondary.”[/i][/b]
                    – Steve Jobs
                       """

        MDBottomAppBar:
            MDToolbar:
                icon: 'book-lock-open' #links to 'ways'
                on_action_button: app.change_screen('ways_screen')
                type: "bottom"
                mode: "center"
                elevation: "8dp"
                left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: x], ["account-group", lambda x: app.change_screen("success_screen")]]
                right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: app.change_screen("search_screen")], ["menu", lambda x: app.change_screen("menu_screen")]]


<MyTile@SmartTileWithLabel>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

<SuccessScreen>
    name: "success_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: success_screen_toolbar
            title: "Success Stories"
            right_action_items: [["progress-clock", lambda x: app.change_screen('goals_screen')]]

        ScrollView:
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                padding: dp(4), dp(4)
                spacing: dp(4)

                MyTile:
                    source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
                    text: "[size=26]Cat 1[/size]\\n[size=14]cat-1.jpg[/size]"

                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = 'bella_baron'

                MyTile:
                    source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
                    text: "[size=26]Cat 2[/size]\\n[size=14]cat-2.jpg[/size]"
                    tile_text_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color

                MyTile:
                    source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"
                    text: "[size=26][color=#ffffff]Cat 3[/color][/size]\\n[size=14]cat-3.jpg[/size]"
                    tile_text_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color

        MDBottomAppBar:
            MDToolbar:
                icon: 'magnify'
                on_action_button: app.change_screen('search_screen')
                type: "bottom"
                mode: "center"
                elevation: "8dp"
                left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: app.change_screen("intro_screen")], ["account-group", lambda x: x]]
                right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: app.change_screen("search_screen")], ["menu", lambda x: app.change_screen("menu_screen")]]


 <SearchScreen>
     name: "search_screen"

    FloatLayout:
         MDBottomAppBar:
            MDToolbar:
                icon: 'window-close'
                type: "bottom"
                mode: "center"
                elevation: "8dp"
                left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: app.change_screen("intro_screen")], ["account-group", lambda x: app.change_screen("success_screen")]]
                right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: x], ["menu", lambda x: app.change_screen("menu_screen")]]

        MDTextField:
            mode: 'fill'
            hint_text: "Search"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5,"center_y": .9}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 280

<MenuScreen>
    name: "menu_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        md_bg_color: (240/255, 240/255, 240/255, 1)

        MDToolbar:
            id: menu_screen_toolbar
            title: "Tools"
            elevation: "8dp"

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "280dp", "360dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - menu_screen_toolbar.height - dp(90)
            y: root.height - menu_screen_toolbar.height - dp(50)
            elevation: 8
            orientation: 'vertical'
            radius: 15

            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Calendar"
                        on_release:
                            app.root.current = "calendar_screen"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "calendar-month"
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Extra"
                        on_release:
                            app.root.current = "extra_screen" 
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "notebook-multiple"
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Archive"
                        on_release:
                            app.root.current = "archive_screen"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "archive"
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: "contact Us"
                        on_release:
                            app.root.current = "contact_info_screen"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "email-mark-as-unread"


        MDBottomAppBar:
            MDToolbar:
                icon: 'reload'
                type: "bottom"
                mode: "center"
                elevation: "8dp"
                left_action_items: [["home", lambda x: app.change_screen("intro_screen")], ["account-group", lambda x: app.change_screen("success_screen")]]
                right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: app.change_screen("search_screen")], ["menu", lambda x: x]]


<WaysScreen>
    name: "ways_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: ways_screen_toolbar
            title: "How-tos"
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('intro_screen')]]
            elevation: "8dp"

        ScrollView:

            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    Image:
                        source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello dear'

                    ScrollView:
                        MDLabel:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text:
                                """Hello, World."""
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello boss'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello goodness'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello hi'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello yes?'

<To_DoScreen>
    name: "to_do_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: to_do_screen_toolbar
            title: 'To-Do-List'
            right_action_items: [['plus', lambda x: x]]
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('intro_screen')]]

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - to_do_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - to_do_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)


<GoalsScreen>
    name: 'goals_screen'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: goals_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Goals'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('success_screen')]]

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "280dp", "360dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - goals_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - goals_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)
            elevation: "8dp"
            orientation: 'vertical'
            radius: 15

<BellaBaron>
    name: 'bella_baron'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: bella_baron_toolbar
            title: "Bella Baron"
            left_action_items: [["keyboard-backspace", lambda x: app.change_screen('success_screen')]]
            right_action_items: [["progress-check", lambda x: app.change_screen('goals_screen')]]

        ScrollView:

            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    Image:
                        source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello dear'

                    ScrollView:
                        MDLabel:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text:
                                """This screens contains a MDcard which where the image is placed, and a MDLabel and neccessary widgets used to tell the success story, under the MDCard."""
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello boss'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello goodness'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello hi'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello yes?'


<CalendarScreen>
    name: "calendar_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: calendar_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Calendar'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]
            right_action_items: [['calendar', lambda x: x]] # on press returns today's date

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - calendar_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - calendar_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)

<ExtraScreen>
    name: "extra_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: extra_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Extra'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]

        ScrollView:

            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 1
                adaptive_height: True
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    Image:
                        source: "C:/Users/HP USER/Downloads/bella_baron.jpg"

                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello dear'

                    ScrollView:
                        MDLabel:
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size: self.texture_size
                            text:
                                """This screens contains a MDcard which where the image is placed, and a MDLabel and neccessary widgets used to tell the success story, under the MDCard."""
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello boss'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello goodness'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello hi'
                MDCard:
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: "280dp", "130dp"
                    radius: 15
                    caption: 'Hello yes?'

<ArchiveScreen>
    name: "archive_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: archive_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Archive'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - archive_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - archive_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)

<Contact_InfoScreen>
    name: "contact_info_screen"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDToolbar:
            id: contact_info_screen_toolbar
            title: 'Contact Info'
            left_action_items: [['keyboard-backspace', lambda x: app.change_screen('menu_screen')]]

        MDCard:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 16
            elevation: 8
            radius: 15
            size_hint: None, None
            size: '280', '360'
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            height: root.height - contact_info_screen_toolbar.height + dp(10)
            y: root.height - contact_info_screen_toolbar.height - dp(20)

            ScrollView:
                MDLabel:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    size: self.texture_size
                    text:
                        """feel free to reach us @"""
```

Comment: you are using `MDBottomAppBar` but you should use https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/bottom-navigation/

Comment: yes I have changed it to bottom navigation.. it;s all working fine now, thanks..